# Play Framework: execute bash shell script - meaning of '>'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, playframework

I'm currently trying to deploy a web application developed with version 2.4 of the Play Framework to an ubuntu server.
Therefore I built a binary version of my project and unzipped it on the server. 
Then when I try to execute the bash shell script that runs the web application I use this command:

```
play-authenticate-usage-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/play-authenticate-usage -Dplay.crypto.secret=Sj]wH]dSn4Wam3R=dsBhd0G:C:lCc5md`L>;iTOpql4hMGZl?77IL15qN6>AHDl4
```

which I found in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying) of the Play Framework.

But when I execute the command the script doesn't start. It seems like it is waiting for more input, since it just shows the '>' symbol in a new line.

Now since I'm not that used to working in the ubuntu terminal, I have no idea what the shell is expecting from me. Is there another command needed to run the shell finally?
Or is it a problem that the crypto key contains semicolons and other symbols?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You have a backtick ` and it's missing the second one.

Comment: Use quotes, like so: `-Dxxxx="yyyy"`

Comment: Use *single* quotes, like so: -Dxxxx='yyyy'

Comment: Single quotes worked! Thank you very much!